# How to enable chat(private chat) with more than one user using smack

Tags: java, chat, smack

I am able to connect to gtalk and facebook server.I can also get the presence of users.Right now I can chat with one person at a time.But I want to chat with more than one users at a time(private chat)

Is it possible to have private chat with more than one users at a time using smack??

If yes then will creating chat via Chatmanager for each destination will solve the problem..
I am confused...

Thanks:)

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question but I hope you can past there some link to this smack and stuff you are talking about, seams interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create a chat via the ChatManager to each destination.  Each chat should have its own message listener as well to distinguish them from each other.